# Calculate Employee Age Correctly

Tags: powerbi, dax

I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere! I am trying to work out the age of employees in my report.

So I have a date table that is used to select a month year (Aug 2020) etc which returns the data for that specific month. I have an employee table with emp name, start date, end date, date of birth, etc.

I am trying to calculate the age of employees from the date of birth until the selected month year. But it is always giving me the incorrect value.

I want to show when I select July 2020 and an employee born on 15/08/1991, this should show as 28. But when I select Aug 2020, this should show as 29. But I am only getting back 29 for whatever month year I select.

Any help would be appreciated!

Yasir

---

```
Employee Age =
VAR SelectedDate =
    MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
VAR CurrentEmployee =
    MAX ( Query1[DATE_OF_BIRTH] )
RETURN
    DATEDIFF ( CurrentEmployee, SelectedDate, YEAR )
```

Comment: What does your DAX formula look like? Is it a measure or a calculated column?

Comment: I have the below dax measure.
Employee Age = 
VAR SelectedDate =MAX('Date'[Date])
VAR CurrentEmployee = MAX(Query1[DATE_OF_BIRTH])
RETURN
DATEDIFF(CurrentEmployee, SelectedDate,YEAR)

Comment: I managed to get this sorted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To compute the age of the employee at the selected date a simple way is to compute the difference between the two dates in days and then divide the result by 365.25

```
Employee Age =
VAR SelectedDate =
    MAX( 'Date'[Date] )
VAR CurrentEmployee =
    MAX( Query1[DATE_OF_BIRTH] )
RETURN
     INT( ( SelectedDate - CurrentEmployee ) / 365.25 )
```

A more precise formula can be found in this article from SQLBI.COM

[Correct calculate of age in DAX from birthday](https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2018/06/24/correct-calculate-of-age-in-dax-from-birthday/)

using `DATEDIFF(CurrentEmployee, SelectedDate, YEAR)` just computes the difference between the years of the two dates, which doesn't work to compute the age.

Comment: Hi Yasir. You are welcome. :)
In order to help you to improve your experience with the stackoverflow community I suggest you this quick reading
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers